# Product of Sierpinski Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given a Sierpinski space $S = \{\{0,1\},\{1\},\emptyset\}$, and suppose we take a Tychonoff space by taking product of $S$ to the power of continuum $S^\mathfrak{c}$.  I am confused about what the open sets of $S^\mathfrak{c}$ looks like.  Each $S$ has a basis $B = \{\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$, but I am not sure how to classify the open sets of the $S^\mathfrak{c}$.  Does it consists of combination of $\{1,1\}$ and $\{1,0\}$?  How about $\{0,0\}$?

Comment: Do not confuse *Tychonoff space* ($=$ completely regular $+$ Hausdorff) with the *Tychonoff product topology*.

Comment: Thanks!   I appreciate the correction!

Answer (score 6):

First, $\big\{\{0,1\},\{1\},\varnothing\big\}$ is not the Sierpiński space: it is the *topology* of the Sierpiński space. The space itself is the set $\{0,1\}$ equipped with this topology, so for the remainder of this answer $S$ will stand for the set $\{0,1\}$, with the understanding that it bears the topology $\big\{\{0,1\},\{1\},\varnothing\big\}$.

Next, as Tyrone pointed out in the comments, $S^\mathfrak{c}$ is not a Tikhonov space; it is, however, the Tikhonov product of $\mathfrak{c}$ copies of $S$. It’s easiest to understand this product if you index the factors, and for that you need an index set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. Fortunately, a very familiar one is on hand: $|\Bbb R|=\mathfrak{c}$, so we can index the factors with real numbers. For each $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ let $S_\alpha$ be a copy of $S$, and let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in\Bbb R}S_x$ with the product topology. Each point $x\in X$ is a function from the index set $\Bbb R$ to $S$; we can write it as $x=\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in\Bbb R\rangle$, where $x_\alpha$ is its coordinate, either $0$ or $1$, in the factor space $S_\alpha$.

For each finite set $F\subseteq\Bbb R$ let

$$U_F=\{x\in X:x_\alpha=1\text{ for all }\alpha\in F\}\,,$$

and let $\mathscr{B}=\{U_F:F\subseteq\Bbb R\text{ is finite}\}$; then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology of $X$.

> You should verify that $\mathscr{B}$ really is the standard base for the product topology, i.e., the collection of all sets of the form $\prod_{\alpha\in\Bbb R}V_\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ is open in $S_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, and at most finitely many of the $V_\alpha$ are not equal to $S_\alpha$.

The open sets in $X$ are therefore precisely the sets that are arbitrary unions of members of $\mathscr{B}$. For example, let $V=\{x\in X:\exists q\in\Bbb Q\,(x_q=1)\}$; then

$$V=\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}U_{\{q\}}\,,$$

so $V$ is a union of members of $\mathscr{B}$ and therefore is an open subset of the product space $X$.

The sets in your last two sentences are not even subsets of $X$, let alone open subsets: the numbers $0$ and $1$ are not elements of $X$.

Comment: Gotcha!  Thanks for your clarification and explanation.  Regarding the terminology, I thought we could say the underlying set S as a Sierpinski space or Sierpinski topology since we know the topology.  But I think proper way to mention space with Sierpinski topology is (S,tau), where tau is Sierpinski topology and S is underlying binary set.

Comment: @Phoenix13: You’re welcome. Yes, a full description would be $\langle S,\tau\}$, where $S=\{0,1\}$ and $\tau=\{\varnothing,\{1\},S\}$. In practice we most often refer to a space by using the name of the underlying set.